# converting columns into rows using cursor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cursor

I am trying to convert columns into rows using cursors. I know people say cursors are the right thing to do. I know we can use pivot to achieve this. But the problem is that client needs it as cursors with a for loop. Not really sure as to why they need it that way but looks like its easier for them to understand the code.

Table A

```
ID  FieldA   FieldB  FieldC 
 1   abc      123     xyz
```

This needs to be converted to

```
ID  Field0
 1   abc
 1   123
 1   xyz
```

Any pointers on how to achieve it could be helpful

Thanks

Prady

Comment: I am sorry.. it should be unpivot... Yeah i know its pretty baffling some feel cursor to be simple... its just way too complicated for me :(

Comment: It is `UNPIVOT` you would need rather than `PIVOT` and I cannot see how cursor code would be anything but less simple. The basic code you need is `SELECT ID,Field0 FROM Table1 UNPIVOT(Field0 FOR FieldName IN (FieldA,FieldB,FieldC)) U`

Comment: What the client wants isn't necessarily what they need...bear that in mind.  I can tell you I need a new server machine that runs on 80486 cpus, and you can do it, but it's not the best solution.

Comment: I suspect it is an interview/teaching task rather then real one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
select ID, FieldA as Field0 from TableA
union all
select ID, FieldB from TableA
union all
select ID, FieldC from TableA
```

Comment: Thats pretty interesting... Didnt know it could be so simple..But client seems to be adamant on cursors